# write array values to file in columns and rows

Tags: c#, formatting

I'm currently stuck on trying to write values input into my array into a file in `rows = 30` and `cols = 5` From my code, its currently writing them straight down. How do i fix this?

CODE:

```
static void PrintReport()
{
  fileOut.WriteLine();
  fileOut.WriteLine("Score       Score       Score       Score       Score");
  fileOut.WriteLine("-----       -----       -----       -----       -----");
  fileOut.WriteLine("");

}

static void InputValues()
{
  int n = 0, row, col;
  int numOfRows, numOfCols;
  string[] words;

  words = fileIn.ReadLine().Split(',');
  numOfRows = Int32.Parse(words[0]);
  numOfCols = Int32.Parse(words[1]);
  numOfValues = numOfRows * numOfCols;
  valueArray = new double[numOfValues + 1];
  for (row = 1; row <= numOfRows; row++)
  {
    words = fileIn.ReadLine().Split(',');
    for (col = 1; col <= numOfCols; col++)
    {
      //n = numOfCols*(row-1) + col; 
      n++;
      valueArray[n] = Double.Parse(words[col - 1]);
    }
  }
}
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

[image: desired output]

Comment: get some help from http://www.domyhomework.com

Comment: "From my code, its currently writing them straight down." -- The code you currently have in `PrintReport()` is not doing anything other than printing a couple strings. I assume you meant to iterate `valueArray` in there.

Comment: i was doing a for loop inside `PrintReport()` such as `for (i = 1; i <= numOfValues; i++)

        fileOut.WriteLine(valueArray[i]);` but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to start writing in the next column after it writes the first values in the first column, in 30 rows.

Comment: You need to change `valueArray` to either `double[][]` and iterate through both arrays for your columns and rows or to a string[] and concatenate the `Double.Parse(words[col - 1]) + "\t"`.

Comment: `valueArray[n] = Double.Parse(words[col - 1]);` is just putting the values into the array, My problem is within print report. It inputs the correct values, I'm just confused on how to get into rows and columns when printing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for formatting, below is a snippet. It works if there are 30x5 always. Else you need to change the logic. The $"" syntax works from C#6.0 only. You need to user string.Format in lower versions. \t is for spacing.You can adjust by increasing 5 also.

```
void Print(double[] valueArray)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row <150; row+=5)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{valueArray[row],5:N2}\t{valueArray[row + 1],5:N2}\t{valueArray[row + 2],5:N2}\t{valueArray[row + 3],5:N2}\t{valueArray[row + 4],5:N2}\t");
        }
    }
```

Comment: okay i get what you did, but that writes the values left to right, and i need to go in ascending order down the columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void PrintReport()
{
  int count;
  fileOut.WriteLine();
  fileOut.WriteLine("Score       Score       Score       Score       Score");
  fileOut.WriteLine("-----       -----       -----       -----       -----");
  for (int row = 1; row <= numOfRows; row++)
  {
    for (int col = 1; col <= numOfCols; col++)
    {
      count = row + numOfRows * (col - 1);
      if (count <= numOfValues)
        fileOut.Write("{0,5:N2}       ", valueArray[count]);
    }
    fileOut.WriteLine();

  }
}
```

this solved my issue